# How use SQL primitive in C# entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, entities

How use SQL primitive in C# entities?

Example:

```
SELECT studentID, studentName 
FROM dbo.Student
```

I did:

```
using(studentEbestuur db = new studentEbestuur())
{
     var ListST = db.ChungLoais.SqlQuery("SELECT studentID, studentName FROM dbo.Student").ToList();
}
```

but I get an error:

[image: error message]

Comment: What is the rest of the "Additional information" ? Please paste the entire exception detail into your question, not an image.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It seems to me that you are looking for something like: `db.ChungLoais.Select(s => new { s.studentId, s.studentName });`

Answer (score 0):

What's the point? You **obviously** have an Entity Framework model of this table - why not use the **Entity Framework** capabilities instead of resorting back to "raw" low-level SQL??

Use this instead:

```
using(studentEbestuur db = new studentEbestuur())
{
     var ListST = db.ChungLoais.Select(x => new { x.studentID, x.studentName }).ToList();
}
```